# Twilio SMS Physical Phone Integration

Tags: sms, twilio, mms, zapier

In a perfect world, the solution I'm looking for would be an api resource tied to my physical phone, e.g. I could POST an sms message to `https://url.com/api/sms`, and this api would have the end result of sending an sms from my physical phone.  This means that the sms conversation would appear natively in my phone; if the recipient replies to the sms, it would appear just as a normal conversation as if I had physically typed the original sms via my phone.

I understand that I could set the replyto/callback/caller-id via Twilio's api.  This would mean that the sms gets sent out by the api, and if the recipient replies to it, I could have the reply forwarded to my phone.  But what would be missing in this scenario is the original message sent via the api, that the recipient is replying to.

Is there a streamlined way to achieve this, perhaps with Zapier?

One arduous solution I have in mind is to write an on-phone-app to intermediate the sms transmission so that I essentially have an sms-controlled api on the physical phone vs. a traditional http api.  (On android, the api would "listen" via `DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` and then send via `sendTextMessage`).  But this seems cumbersome and would also require updating the app code when/if android changes the underlying `SmsManager` library.  The advantage of this is that I could avoid Twilio altogether, by using my service provider's email-to-sms to send to the on-phone-makeshift-sms-api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you are looking for a [feature that we just announced in preview](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/announcing-phone-numbers-in-70-countries-transparent-toll-free-pricing-and-hosted-sms.html#hosted_sms). This is known as Hosted SMS and allows you to add SMS powered by Twilio to your existing phone number.

You need to [apply to get access to Hosted SMS](https://www.twilio.com/sms/hosted) as it is newly in testing. You can do so with the form here: https://www.twilio.com/sms/hosted

Comment: Is there any estimated time as to when this is going to be fully released?  I applied for the early access, but no idea how long it will take for a response. (I only applied yesterday evening- assuming nobody is around to answer those during the weekend regardless.) This is the exact feature we're looking for- we're already customers of Twilio, but not being able to respond to the users in a single clean conversation is a pain-point.

Comment: I don't have an estimate on when this will be come open publicly. You are right that you won't get an answer over the weekend. Hopefully you will hear something soon 

Answer (score 1):

I've set up texting to a physical phone by using Twilio's SIM cards and associating it to a phone number.